# CTest not detecting tests

Tags: cmake, makefile, ctest

I have a project with a structure

```
├── CMakeLists.txt
├── mzl.c
├── mzl.h
└── tests
    ├── CMakeLists.txt
    ├── mzl-communication-test.c
    ├── mzl-setup-test.c
    ├── mzl-test-errors.c
    └── mzl-test-errors.h
```

Where the top directory `CMakeLists.txt` file is

```
project(mzl)
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8)

add_subdirectory(tests)

# Enable testing for the project
enable_testing()

# Find zmq
find_library(ZMQ_LIB zmq REQUIRED)
message(STATUS "ZMQ Library: ${ZMQ_LIB}")

# Find threading library
set(CMAKE_THREAD_PREFER_PTHREAD ON)
find_package(Threads REQUIRED)
message(STATUS "Threading Library: ${CMAKE_THREAD_LIBS_INIT}")



# Set include directories for headers
set     (
    MZL_INCLUDE_DIRS
    ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}
    CACHE STRING "MZL Include Directories"
    )
include_directories(${MZL_INCLUDE_DIRS})

# Set source files
set     (
    MZL_SRC_FILES
    mzl.c
    )

# Add library
add_library(${PROJECT_NAME} STATIC ${MZL_SRC_FILES})

# Link to zmq
target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} ${ZMQ_LIB} ${CMAKE_THREAD_LIBS_INIT})
```

and `tests/CMakeLists.txt` is

```
# Use MZL Source Directories (mzl headers are in top directory)
include_directories(${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR})

# Variable from here is empty
message(STATUS "MZL Include Directories: ${MZL_INCLUDE_DIRS}")

# Files common to all tests
set ( TEST_COMMON_SOURCES
    mzl-test-errors.c
    )

# Library setup/shutdown testing
set(SETUP_TEST_NAME mzl-setup-test)
add_executable(${SETUP_TEST_NAME} ${TEST_COMMON_SOURCES} ${SETUP_TEST_NAME}.c)
target_link_libraries(${SETUP_TEST_NAME} ${PROJECT_NAME} ${ZMQ_LIB})
add_test(${SETUP_TEST_NAME} ${SETUP_TEST_NAME})

# Communcations test
set(COMMUNICATION_TEST_NAME mzl-communication-test)
add_executable(${COMMUNICATION_TEST_NAME} ${TEST_COMMON_SOURCES}
    ${COMMUNICATION_TEST_NAME}.c)
target_link_libraries(${COMMUNICATION_TEST_NAME} ${PROJECT_NAME}
        ${CMAKE_THREAD_LIBS_INIT} ${ZMQ_LIB})
add_test(${COMMUNICATION_TEST_NAME}  ${COMMUNICATION_TEST_NAME})
```

Everything worked fine before I added the second test `mzl-communication-test`. After adding it and the lines in the `tests/CMakeLists.txt` after `# Communications test`, running `ctest` did nothing extra -- it still only ran the first test.

After deleting the build directory and running `cmake` again, I get no errors for the initial CMake run, but running `make` runs CMake again, resulting in an error with CMake:

```
CMake Error: Parse error in cache file build/CMakeCache.txt. Offending entry: include
```

followed by a Make error:

```
Makefile:203: recipe for target 'cmake_check_build_system' failed
make: *** [cmake_check_build_system] Error 1
```

Running `make` again results in everything being built, including the tests; however, running `ctest` results in

```
Test project build
No tests were found!!!
```

The issue seems to be with something that I am doing with CMake, but can't figure out what to do from here as I can't see anything that I'm doing differently than when it was originally working. Even my last commit to git, which was working when I committed it, is no longer working.

Comment: Looks like a quote character is missing in the assignment statement `set (MZL_INCLUDE_DIRS ...` in the top `CMakeLists.txt`.

Comment: @sakra It seems that this is a problem, but when I fix this and remove the unneeded `include` in `MZL_INCLUDE_DIRS`, the variable is no longer set in `tests/CMakeLists.txt`.

Comment: It also seems that even if I fix that issue by just using `..` as the include directory for the tests, there are still no tests found.

Comment: Please update the listing of your CMakeLists.txt now.

Answer (score 78, accepted):

You need to move the `enable_testing()` call to be before you do `add_subdirectory(tests)`

```
# Enable testing for the project
enable_testing()

add_subdirectory(tests)
```

Comment: Can't believe I missed this. This also fixed the issue with variables not being defined in child directories. Thanks!

Comment: This is one of those examples where a simple note could make a developers live so much easier. `No tests were found!!! Did you define enable_testing() before add_subdirectory()?`

Comment: @lanoxx +1 to your point.   Furthermore wouldn't it be great if the GoogleTest quick start (https://google.github.io/googletest/quickstart-cmake.html) mentioned tests in subdirectories?